# calculate level of child category in sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table that stores parent and child ids, An id can have multiple sub categories, sub categories can have further categories and that can continue ) I have two columns "id" and "parentid" to store that info.

I need to populate the third column "level" that explain the hierarchy level of a category so that all the categories that got no child would have level = 1
, sub categories that inherit from parent category would have level = 2, similarly all sub categories who inherits from sub catogories that further inherit from main parent categories would have level =3 ...and this would follow

How do I populate the "level" field here

Comment: check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making a huge assumption that you are using MS SQL SERVER you can use self referencing (or recursive) CTE's

```
;WITH CTE (id, p_id, level)
AS 
(SELECT s.id, null,1
    FROM table1 s
    where parent_id is null

  UNION ALL

 SELECT s.id,parent_id,m.level + 1
   FROM CTE m
   JOIN table1 s on m.id = s.parent_id
 )
update table1 set level = c.level 
from cte c
where table1.id = c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you described it: First update all records hat have no children to get level 1, then their parents to get level 2, etc. As you did not state the DBMS neither the language you want to use, the following contains some pseudo code:

```
<declare and initialize a variable "@lvl" to 1>

-- SQL:
update category set level = 1
 where not exists(select 1
                    from category as parent
                   where catergory.parentId = parent.id)

<while the last update updated some rows>
    -- SQL:
    update category set level = @lvl + 1
     where exists(select 1
                    from category as child
                   where child.parentId = category.id
                     and child.level = @lvl)
    <increment lvl by 1>
<end of while loop>
```